Does the italicized part serve as the main clause of the whole sentence?
That is, can I paraphrase the sentence as 'Classical writers claimed that it was only after shadows had become an established, if controversial, part of representation that  art itself had begun with the tracing of a human shadow.'?
Or, does it just function as the main clause of  that art itself had begun with the tracing of a human shadow.?

Shadows have been part of Western artistic practice since its origins.
As far back as 32,000 years ago, prehistoric cave artists skillfully
used modeling shadows to give their horses and bison volume. A few
thousand years ago ancient Egyptian and then archaic Greek art
presented human forms in shadow-style silhouette. But cast shadows do
not appear in Western art until about 400 BCE in Athens. It was only
after shadows had become an established, if controversial, part of
representation that classical writers claimed that art itself
had begun with the tracing of a human shadow. Greeks and Romans were
the first to make the transition from modeling shadows to cast
shadows, a practice that implied a consistent light source, a fixed
point of view, and an understanding of geometric projection. In fact,
what we might now call “shadow studies” ― the exploration of shadows
in their various artistic manifestations ― has its roots in ancient
Athens. Ever since, the practice of rendering shadows has evolved in
tandem with critical analysis of them, as artists and theoreticians
have engaged in an ongoing debate about the significance of shadow
representation.

Grasping Shadows: The Dark Side of Literature, Painting, Photography, and Film
By William Chapman Sharpe

Why paraphrase it at all? What's the point? It'a perfectly formed sentence.
